# Output wrapping div only if there is at least 1 element (in array)

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following (Symfony 2) PHP Template:

```
<?php 
$messages = $view['session']->getFlashes();
if (count($messages) > 0) : ?>
<section id="flashMessages">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $key => $msg) : ?>
        <li class="<?php $key ?>">
            <?php echo $msg ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to convert to `twig` in a simple way. How can I do that? Can I even `count()` in twig? In twig, theres the `else` in the `for` loop but I want the `section#flashMessages` to show only if there are flash messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% set messages = app.session.getFlashes() %}

{% if messages | length > 0 %} {# or just `if messages` #}
    <section id="flashMessages">
        <ul>
            {% for key, msg in messages %}
                <li class="{{ key }}">
                    {{ msg }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </section>
{% endif %}
```

Sorry, written right here — have no time to test it. But this should be good enough to show you the concepts.